# aggregate data based on frequency in sql

Tags: sql

I've a sample dataset

```
order_id    email             product_id       order_date
   1        xyz@gmail.com         1            2023-05-23
   1        xyz@gmail.com         2            2023-05-23
   2        abc@gmail.com         1            2023-05-26
   3        xyz@gmail.com         3            2023-06-01
   4        abc@gmail.com         3            2023-06-02
   5        ijk@gmail.com         1            2023-06-10
   6        klm@gmail.com         1            2023-06-11
   7        xyz@gmail.com         4            2023-06-14
```

end aggregate table would like

```
order_frequency     #of users       avg_gap_between_orders
     1                  2                  null
     >=2                2                   9
     >=3                1                   11
```

**>=2** represents customers who have order alteast two times.
There are two customers who ordered atleast twice. For first user `xyz@gmail.com` the average_gap_between_orders is 11 days (2022-05-23 <9 days> 2023-06-01 <13 days> 2023-06-14) and for the second customer it is 7 days (2023-05-26 <7days> 2023-06-02).

I tried using my current sql skills, but unable to get the desired result.

How can this be achieved using sql?

Query tried:

```
select case when order_count = 1 then '1'
            when order_count >=2 then '>=2'
            when order_count >=3 then '>=3'
       end as order_frequency, 
       count(distinct email) users
from (
    select email, count(distinct order_num) order_count
    from orders
    group by email) s1
group by order_frequency;
```

Comment: Please include the query you have tried so far, even though it's not providing the desired result.

Comment: I did @Stu. But the query didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query:

```
with e as (
  select em, cnt, avg(diff) av
  from (  
    select em, count(1) over (partition by em) cnt, dt,
           datediff(dt, lag(dt) over (partition by em order by dt)) diff
    from (select distinct order_id oid, email em, order_date dt from orders) o ) o
  group by em, cnt )
select ' =1' freq, count(1) cnt, avg(av) gap from e where cnt = 1 union all
select '>=2', count(1), avg(av) from e where cnt >= 2 union all
select '>=3', count(1), avg(av) from e where cnt >= 3
```

Postgres query is similar, but without datediff:

```
with e as (
  select em, cnt, avg(diff) av
  from (  
    select em, count(1) over (partition by em) cnt, dt,
           dt - lag(dt) over (partition by em order by dt) diff
    from (select distinct order_id oid, email em, order_date dt from orders) o ) o
  group by em, cnt )
select ' =1' freq, count(1) cnt, avg(av) gap from e where cnt = 1 union all
select '>=2', count(1), avg(av) from e where cnt >= 2 union all
select '>=3', count(1), avg(av) from e where cnt >= 3
```

[dbfiddle Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/9lb0_fu0) and [dbfiddle in MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCySQS6B)

Idea is to make statistics for each email (done in subquery `e`), then count and calculate average values for desired groups. At first I made distinct orders, because for order_id=1 there are two rows and you count it only once.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest calculate the MIN and MAX for ORDER_DATE field at the subselect where you're grouping by. After that you can calculate the average by a simple division operation (MAX - MIN) / order_count.

You may need to subtract order_count from calculation (MAX - MIN) if you want exclude the outer dates. In your example, it is not necessary (just in case).

Pay attention how you will treat average for customers with only 1 order (0/1) = 0. You can override the result in that cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a case expression to solve this problem as you did, the case expression will stop once a condition is met, i.e. for your case it will return '>=2' for any value that's greater than or equal to 2, and it will not reach the condition `>=3`.

The problem is that you have overlapping groups, where the same value should be aggregated by more than one group. We could do a left join to solve it as the following (for MySQL 8.x):

```
with frequencies as
( -- list all of your frequencies
  select 1 as val, '=1' as frq union all
  select 2, '>=2' union all
  select 3, '>=3'
)
select f.frq order_frequency,
       count(*) '#of users', 
       avg(avg_df_per_email) avg_gap_between_orders
from frequencies f left join 
  (
    select email, count(distinct order_id) cn,
           datediff(max(order_date), min(order_date)) /(count(distinct order_date)-1) avg_df_per_email
    from table_name group by email
 ) t 
on f.val<=t.cn
where (f.val=1 and t.cn=1) or f.val>1  -- to exclude rows where cn>1 are joined to f.val=1
group by f.frq
```

The `datediff(max(order_date), min(order_date)) /(count(distinct order_date)-1) avg_df_per_email` is used to calculate the average of order_date gaps for each user, it's equivalent to calculating the difference between each date and it's previous date then find the average of that difference.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AT0IqQas)

For Postgres, you have to modify the line that calculate the average of order_date gaps for each user as the following:

```
(max(order_date) - min(order_date)) /nullif((count(distinct order_date)-1), 0) avg_df_per_email
```

Remove the `dateddiff` function and use date subtraction instead, and use `nullif` function to implement a safe division in case `count(distinct order_date)-1` is equal to 0.

> For MySQL, by default, division by zero produces a result of NULL and no warning.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5iV_RMpB) on Postgres

Answer (score 0):

The following PostgreSQL query will produce the specified results:

```
WITH spans AS (
  SELECT o.email,
         count(DISTINCT o.order_id) AS num_orders,
         max(o.order_date) - min(o.order_date) AS order_span
    FROM orders o
    GROUP BY o.email)
SELECT to_char(f.n, CASE f.n WHEN 1 THEN 'FM9' ELSE '>=FM9' END) AS order_frequency,
       count(DISTINCT s.email) AS "#of users",
       avg(s.order_span / (nullif(s.num_orders, 1) - 1.0)) AS avg_gap_between_orders
  FROM generate_series(1, (SELECT max(s.num_orders)
                             FROM spans s)) f(n)
  JOIN spans s ON CASE f.n WHEN 1 THEN s.num_orders = 1 ELSE s.num_orders >= f.n END
  GROUP BY f.n
  ORDER BY f.n;
```

The CTE, `spans`, determines the number of orders placed by each user and the date span between those orders.

The main query computes the mean of the mean gap between orders for each user. The mean gap for each user is computed by dividing the span for that user by the number of gaps between that user's orders. The number of gaps is one less than the number of orders. The value `1.0` is used instead of `1` so that the result will be rounded instead of truncated. The function, `nullif`, is used to avoid division by zero exceptions.

A series is used to generate frequency labels for all frequencies from 1 to the maximum number of orders placed by any user (I'm using the term *frequency* to be consistent with the original post even though it's actually an occurrence count). This approach handles any number of frequencies without requiring changes to the query and also avoids gaps in the output; e.g., if the OP's sample data had no user with exactly three orders, but had a user with four orders, then the frequency labels would be `1`, `>=2`, `>=3`, and `>=4` with the last two having the same `#of users` and `avg_gap_between_orders`.